# Getting SSL Error when connection to yahoo.com (yfinance)

Tags: python, ssl, yfinance

Since days I get an error when trying to connect to yahoo (or in detail using yfinance in python) running on my local machine. The script worked fine until last week. However, the source code seems fine since it still runs in Google´s Colab.

I found a script to check for the used SSL version on https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html. The following code works with any tested hostname except yahoo.

```
import socket
import ssl

hostname = 'www.yahoo.com'
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        print(ssock.version())
```

This is the error:

```
SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
l:\Shared Documents\Coding\Python\Jupyter\playground.ipynb Cell 1' in <module>
      5 context = ssl.create_default_context()
      7 with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:
----> 8     with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
      9         print(ssock.version())

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py:512, in SSLContext.wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    506 def wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side=False,
    507                 do_handshake_on_connect=True,
    508                 suppress_ragged_eofs=True,
    509                 server_hostname=None, session=None):
    510     # SSLSocket class handles server_hostname encoding before it calls
    511     # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 512     return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    513         sock=sock,
    514         server_side=server_side,
    515         do_handshake_on_connect=do_handshake_on_connect,
    516         suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs,
    517         server_hostname=server_hostname,
    518         context=self,
    519         session=session
    520     )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py:1070, in SSLSocket._create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1067         if timeout == 0.0:
   1068             # non-blocking
   1069             raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1070         self.do_handshake()
   1071 except (OSError, ValueError):
   1072     self.close()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py:1341, in SSLSocket.do_handshake(self, block)
   1339     if timeout == 0.0 and block:
   1340         self.settimeout(None)
-> 1341     self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1342 finally:
   1343     self.settimeout(timeout)

SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)
```

One thing to add: The only thing that changed for my local machine since last weekend is: I´m now on wifi instead of ethernet. But how *could' this cause that kind of error?